# Can a parent take away their minor child's earned wages or gifts? (TX, USA)

Tags: minor, children, parental-rights

If a minor 16 or 17 years old in Texas  has a job and earns wages or receives any sort of gifts from friends and extended family, can their parents legally take their possessions and a) sell them, or b) take them for personal use ("your spending money just became mine" kind of situation)?

Is the answer different depending on whether these possessions are money or objects? If a child used their own money earned through their own labor to purchase something, can their parents legally take those things and sell them or use them themselves?

And as a related question to this one, in the case that a parent was allowed to seize property for "safekeeping", what would happen to their ownership of those items if the child turns 18 or the parent otherwise loses custody?